# Can a sitting U.S. Senator run against the other sitting U.S. Senator in a state?

Tags: us-senate

I'm wondering, could a sitting U.S. Senator run against the other sitting U.S. Senator in that state?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be on Politics.SE.

Comment: It's a legal question, but it also relates to politics.

Comment: @TimLymington: This is a legal question, not a political one, though its about the law governing who may run for political offices. Specifically, it is dealing with a peculiarity of the US legislature. In the lower chamber of Congress, the House of Representatives, there is one representative for each district, in the same way that there is one MP for each constituency in the House of Commons. However, in the upper house, two Senators are elected (for offset terms) to represent a collection of districts (which happens to be a semi-autonomous State).

Comment: It might be possible under the rules, but it would be pretty pointless, since the senator running for early reelection would preumably have to resign the other seat after winning, triggering a special election.  The only reason to do this would be if the senator seeking early reelection believed that his or her chances were significantly better than they would be in two or four years' time.

Comment: Or if the other senator were of the other party.

Answer (score 1):

The only requirements are those specified in the Constitution, regarding age, citizenship and residence. [Title 2 of the US Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/2/chapter-1) has laws regarding elections governing timing of elections and soon, but nothing like a law saying "No sitting US Senator can run for the other senatorial position in his state". [This article](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R41946.pdf) reviews aspects of congressional qualifications, and it is noted that the courts find that the constitutional qualifications are exclusive, meaning that there can't be such additional requirements. Therefore, convicted felons can be US Senators.